# uploading a file to google cloud by converting a file buffer

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to upload a file to google cloud by accepting a buffer and using the `save` function. However, my problem is that my files are not uploading to google cloud in the right format. They get uploaded, but when I try downloading the file, they are all .txt files of the buffer.

I'm not really sure what I should be doing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**upload.ts**

```
const upload = async (fileBuffer: any, filePath: string, fileName: string) => {
    const file = bucket.file(path.join(filePath, fileName));
    file.save(fileBuffer, (err: any) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

**storage.ts**

```
imageSender: async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const buffer = "";

        await upload(buffer, "folder", "file");

        res.status(200).send("The file was successfully uploaded.");

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(httpError(500, "Could not upload the file."));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was actually taking in a base64 string and not a buffer, so I just added `const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64');`. It worked perfectly after that!